# Integrate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{x^2+2x+4}\ dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What is $$\int_0^\infty  \frac{\log x}{x^2+2x+4}\ dx$$

Here's a hint that came along with the problem,

> Substitute $x$ as $2t$ and write it as a sum of two integrals. Then try to simplify.

Comment: And what happened when you followed the hint?

Comment: This is the integral
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{(x+1)^2 + 3}\,dx
$$
use integration by parts before applying the hint.

Comment: u could also do contour integration

Comment: @ClementC. I followed that hint and see what happened and came up with an answer. Is that what you would get too?

Comment: @imranfat I was getting to "If the OP followed the hint and and got stuck, showing the work done and where (s)he got stuck is exactly the kind of things that will help us help him/her. If the OP did not try anything yet, then trying something -- e.g., the substitution suggested by the hint -- is the first step."

Comment: I did eventually solve this one, but by giving a substitution that x=t/4 , as done below.Check it out, it is way simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will give it a try here. I also think this problem can be done without integration by parts, but the hint from the OP is very useful.

Using $x=2t$ we get
$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{x^2+2x+4}\ dx$ = $2\int_0^\infty \frac{\log 2} {4t^2+4t+4}\ dt$ + $2\int_0^\infty \frac{\log t}{4t^2+4t+4}\ dt.$

The first integral:
Take the log term upfront and factor a $4$ from the denom. Complete the square on the denom and integrate accordingly to arrive at an arctan.
When you plug in values, you get $\frac{{\pi}log2}{\sqrt{27}}$ which is approx $0.18200$
It turns out that this is the answer to the integral. (With TI integrating from $0$ to $1000$ I came to $0.1787$)
Done? Of course not.

What about that second integral?
Let s call that integral $I$. Here is the trick: Perform a u-sub $t=\frac{1}{v}$
You can verify that you get essentially the same integral back with a negative coefficient upfront; that is $I=-cI$ from which it follows that $I=0.$
So I suspect this is the reason why you were given that hint, it is a very good one!

Comment: All too easy.  +1 ;-))

Comment: Nice trick, by the way. if the integrand is $log(x)/(x^2+ax+b)$ with $b>0$, the trick would work too (change of variable $y=\sqrt{b}x$)

Answer (score 20):

**Another Approach**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^2+2x+4}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(4)-\log(x)}{x^2+2x+4}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\log(2)\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+2x+4}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac{\log(2)}{\sqrt3}\int_{1/\sqrt3}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+1}\tag{3}\\
&=\frac{\pi\log(2)}{3\sqrt3}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto\frac4x$
$(2)$: average left and right sides of $(1)$
$(3)$: substitute $x\mapsto\sqrt3\,x-1$
$(4)$: arctan integral

Comment: by far the nicest one (+1)

Comment: Yeah, that's rather quick...+1

Comment: Excellent as always!  +1

Comment: This is the like the alternate, hard to see but super easy to understand ,type of solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To precise Imranfat answer,

$\displaystyle J=\int_0^\infty  \dfrac{\log x}{x^2+2x+4}\ dx$

Apply the change of variable $x=2t$,

$\displaystyle J=\int_0^\infty  \dfrac{\log (2t)}{2(t^2+t+1)}\ dt=\int_0^\infty  \dfrac{\log 2}{2(t^2+t+1)}dt+\int_0^\infty  \dfrac{\log t}{2(t^2+t+1)}dt$

In the right member the second integral is equal to zero,

$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty  \dfrac{\log (t)}{2(t^2+t+1)}\ dt=\int_0^1  \dfrac{\log (t)}{2(t^2+t+1)}\ dt+\int_1^\infty  \dfrac{\log (t)}{2(t^2+t+1)}\ dt$

Perform in the second integral the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$, thus,

$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty  \dfrac{\log (t)}{2(t^2+t+1)}\ dt=\int_0^1  \dfrac{\log (t)}{2(t^2+t+1)}\ dt-\int_0^1  \dfrac{\log (t)}{2(t^2+t+1)}\ dt=0$

$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty  \dfrac{\log 2}{2(t^2+t+1)}dx=\left[\ \dfrac{\log 2}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\dfrac{1+2x}{\sqrt{3}}\right) \right]_0^\infty=\dfrac{\pi\log 2}{3\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Yep. And what that essentially means for that second integral is that the net area is zero. That is, the area under the x-axis (from 0 to 1) is equal to the area above the x-axis (from 1 to inf)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I will present another method:

1. Compute:

$$\mathscr{S}_\text{n}:=\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{n}}\left\{\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\left(\text{n}x\right)}{x^2+2x+4}\space\text{d}x\right\}=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+2x+4}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{n}}\left(\ln\left(\text{n}x\right)\right)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+2x+4}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{n}}\left(\ln\left(\text{n}\right)+\ln\left(x\right)\right)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+2x+4}\cdot\left\{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{dn}}\left(\ln\left(\text{n}\right)\right)+\ln\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{n}}\left(1\right)\right\}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

2. Now, find:

$$\mathcal{I}:=\int_1^2\mathscr{S}_\text{n}\space\text{dn}\tag2$$

3. Prove that the integral you want to find is equal to $\mathcal{I}$;
4. You will/must find:

$$\mathcal{I}=\frac{\pi\ln\left(2\right)}{3\sqrt{3}}\tag3$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaystyle{L1:\int\limits_0^\infty  {\sin ax \cdot {e^{ - sx}}dx}  = \frac{a}{{{s^2} + {a^2}}}}$$ , $$\displaystyle{L2:\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\sin ax}}{x} \cdot {e^{ - sx}}dx}  = \arctan \frac{a}{s}}$$ ,
$$\displaystyle{L3:\int\limits_0^\infty  {\log x \cdot {e^{ - sx}}dx}  =  - \frac{{\log s + \gamma }}{s}}$$ $$\displaystyle{L4:\int\limits_0^\infty  {\sin ax \cdot \log x \cdot {e^{ - sx}}dx}  =  - \frac{1}{{2i}} \cdot \left( {\frac{{\log \left( {s - ia} \right) + \gamma }}{{s - ia}} - \frac{{\log \left( {s + ia} \right) + \gamma }}{{s + ia}}} \right)}$$

$$\displaystyle{L5:\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\sin ax \cdot \log x}}{x} \cdot {e^{ - sx}}dx}  =  - \frac{1}{{2i}} \cdot \int\limits_s^\infty  {\left( {\frac{{\log \left( {u - ia} \right) + \gamma }}{{u - ia}} - \frac{{\log \left( {u + ia} \right) + \gamma }}{{u + ia}}} \right)du}  =  - \left( {\gamma  + \frac{{\log \left( {{s^2} + {a^2}} \right)}}{2}} \right) \cdot \arctan \frac{a}{s}}$$

$$\displaystyle{\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\log x}}{{{x^2} + 2x + 4}}dx}  = \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\log x}}{{{{\left( {x + 1} \right)}^2} + 3}}dx}  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\log x\left( {\int\limits_0^\infty  {\sin \left( {\sqrt 3 t} \right){e^{ - \left( {x + 1} \right)t}}dt} } \right)dx}  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\sin \left( {\sqrt 3 t} \right){e^{ - t}}\left( {\int\limits_0^\infty  {\log x \cdot {e^{ - xt}}dx} } \right)dt}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ =  - \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\sin \left( {\sqrt 3 t} \right){e^{ - t}}\frac{{\log t + \gamma }}{t}dt}  =  - \frac{\gamma }{{\sqrt 3 }}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\sin \left( {\sqrt 3 t} \right)}}{t}{e^{ - t}}dt}  - \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\sin \left( {\sqrt 3 t} \right)\log t}}{t}{e^{ - t}}dt}  = \mathop {\mathop  = \limits_{a = \sqrt 3 {\text{ \&  }}s = 1} }\limits^{L2{\text{ \&  }}L5}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ =  - \frac{\gamma }{{\sqrt 3 }}\frac{\pi }{3} + \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\left( {\gamma  + \log 2} \right) \cdot \frac{\pi }{3} \Rightarrow \boxed{\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\log x}}{{{x^2} + 2x + 4}}dx}  = \frac{{\pi \log 2}}{{3\sqrt 3 }}}}$$